# How to remove special characters from a string in MongoDB field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, character

I would like to remove all special characters like “: ” + “. ” from the below string.

First I did a match to remove all the null values.  Then I did a project,  it does not seem to remove the special characters from the string.

**TES:** At the end of the season, the teams have not played to the standard:  expect some changes to the rotation.

Output should be the following:  At the end of the season the teams have not played to the standard  expected some changes to the rotation

Here is my code:  Let me know what I am doing wrong please.

```
$match :
{
  'TES': {$exists:   true,   $ne: 'null' }, 
},
$project:
{
  message : 
  { 
    $reduce: 
    {
      "input": 
       {
          $split: ["$TES", "\\:", "."]
       },  
       "initialValue": "", 
       "in": { $concat: ["$$this", " ", "$$value"] }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include a **sample input string** with these special characters you want removed. Also, mention what **all special characters** you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks All, it actually works for (":").  Sorry.